# How to access the datasource from a REST service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I have a ArcGIS REST service, is it possible to access the data source of the layer that is within the rest service. For example I have a layer called "Conservation Area" within the service, that references the dataset "PLANNING.CONSERVATION_AREAS". It is "PLANNING.CONSERVATION_AREAS" that i want to retrieve back. Is this possible

**EDIT**
I want to get access to the actual feature class name which is held within the database (oracle in my case).
I have read about the Data Source object [REST Data Source Object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r30000019q000000) which does suggest it is possible ? (but not sure how).

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the SOAP API as well here http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/soap/10.1/index.html#/Overview/01vp0000009n000000/. I am not aware of any way to do this via REST API. Another way to try is to test using geodata services, they expose more "geodatabase information" than regular map services. REST Data Source object won't help you here since you have to specify the path to the feature class to work with and in your case you are trying to figure out the one.

Answer (score 1):

When you go to your REST services should be something like "yoururl/ArcGIS/rest/services"
If you have admin access you should see a list of services, which then you can click on. 
The next page should then list the layers you have in that service.

Comment: This will just give the layer name back (as defined within the .mxd), but not the actual feature class name (as defined within the database). Halil wants to get back the feature class name, i.e., dbo.Planning.CONSERVATION_AREAS. This information is not exposed directly in ArcGIS Services Directory.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I misunderstood.
Halil, If this is what you want, you should clarify your question to specify feature class name.

Is it exclusive to REST? If you really want the datasource why not look directly at the mxds?